# Ring with all elements dividing zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

Let $A$ and $B$ be commutative rings.

I want to show that if every element except $1$ in $A \times B$ divides zero, then all elements except $1$ in $A$ and $B$ divide zero.

My try is :

$\forall(a,b)\in A \times B \setminus \{1\} ~\exists (a',b')\in A \times B \setminus \{0\}$ such that $(a,b)(a',b')=(aa',bb')=(0,0)=0$.

So we have $aa'=0$ and $bb'=0$.

At this point I don't see how can I handle elements like $(0,b')$ or $(a',0)$. Any hints ?

Comment: You don't care about them, you already proved that all elements of $A$ and $B$ (except 1) are zero divisors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an arbitrary $a\in A, a\ne 0$.

Look at the element $(a,1)\ne(0,0)$. It divides zero, so $(a,1)(a',b')=(0,0)$ for some $(a', b')\ne(0,0)$. This means $aa'=0$ and $b'=0$. The latter implies that $a'\ne 0$ (as $(a',b')\ne(0,0)$), so $a$ divides zero.